# How to calculate variance in a Poisson process with exponential lifetimes of arrivals?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, exponential-distribution, poisson-process

I am trying to understand how to combine the concepts of Poisson process and the birth and death process.

I have a Poisson process where people arrive with rate $\lambda$  --  so when an event occurs, a new person arrives.  Suppose the lifetime of each person is independent Exponential $($$\mu$$)$.

Further, let $M$$($$t$$)$ be the number of people at time $t$.  I take that $M(t)$ $=$ $10$.  So, at time $t$, there are $10$ people.

Now, I would like to calculate $Var[$$M$$(t + s)$ $|$ $M(t)$ $=$ $10$$]$, where $0$ $<$ $t$ $<$ $s$.

I have this question because I have been studying about independent increments in Poisson processes.  Here, we have $2$ disjoint intervals: $[$$0$, $t$$)$ and $[$$t$, $s$$)$.  If this was just a standard Poisson process, we can say that the number of events until time $t$ is independent of the number of events in the interval $[$$t$, $t+s$$)$.

But the case at hand is a bit different, because the lifetimes of the events/people are $iid$, and distributed as $L$ ~ Exponential $($$\mu$$)$.  This means each event/person lives for an exponential $($$\mu$$)$ amount of time.

Given this, how can I proceed here?  I tried working out a few things but I am stuck while trying to calculate conditional variance, and any advice on the direction to follow would be very helpful.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you so much for your reply!  I am trying to understand and would like to ask a clarifying question if that's okay.  In a standard Poisson process, $M(t)$ will be the number of arrivals/events until time $t$.  But here, along with the standard Poisson process, we have each person dying after Exponential $(Mu)$ amount of time.  And $M(t)$ is the number of people at time $t$.  Given this, is $M(t)$ also a Poisson process? How can we make $M(t)$ take into account the exponential lifetime of each individual? Any advice would help me understand the concept.  Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I mis-read the question. What you have is a birth and death process. A good reference is Karlin's (two volume) book.

Comment: Thank you!  I will study that and then work on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to the calculation:

- The ten alive at time $t$: each has an independent probability of being alive at time $t+s$ of $e^{-\mu s}$ and so their binomial  contribution to the expectation is $10 e^{-\mu s}$ and to the variance is $10 e^{-\mu s}(1-e^{-\mu s})$
- Any individuals who might arrive at time $a$ with $t < a \le t+s$ (at a rate $\lambda$)  and still be alive at time $t+s$ with probability $e^{-\mu(t+s-a)}$.  In effect we have a non-homogeneous Poisson process with parameter varying over time $\lambda  e^{-\mu(t+s-a)}$ amounting to a combined Poisson distribution with parameter $\int_t^{t+s} \lambda e^{-\mu(t+s-a)}\, da = \frac{\lambda}{\mu}\left(1-e^{-\mu s}\right)$ and this is their contribution to both the mean and the variance.

Putting these together:

- $\mathbb E[T(t+s) \mid T(t)=10] = 10 e^{-\mu s} + \frac{\lambda}{\mu}\left(1-e^{-\mu s}\right)$
- $\mathrm{Var}(T(t+s) \mid T(t)=10) = 10 e^{-\mu s}\left(1-e^{-\mu s}\right) + \frac{\lambda}{\mu}\left(1-e^{-\mu s}\right) = \left(10 e^{-\mu s}+\frac{\lambda}{\mu} \right) \left(1-e^{-\mu s}\right)$

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!  I am trying to understand the steps here.  So the lifetimes of individuals are random variables that are $iid$ Exponential $(μ)$.  I was thinking that for the $10$ alive at time $t$, each one has an independent probability of being alive at time $t+s$ of $\mu$$e^{-\mu s}$ (the probability density of the exponential random variable).  I'd be grateful for any advice on why the probability of being alive at time $t+s$ is $e^{-\mu s}$.  I think I am probably missing something here... Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh I get it now.  I worked it out step by step.  So we get $P($ being alive at time $t+s$$)$ $=$ $P($$L$ $>=$ $t+s$ $|$ $L > t$$)$ $=$ $P($$L+t$ $>=$ $t+s$$)$ $=$ $P($$L$ $>=$ $s$$)$ $=$ $e^{-\mu s}$ .  I hope I am understanding this correct.

Comment: @MilesToGo That is correct for those present at time $t$.  It is the memoryless property of the exponential distribution

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming!

Comment: I have a follow-up question here.  Suppose at a certain time, we just have $1$ person.  I'm trying to find the probability that there will be no people remaining when this $1$ person dies.  I did the following:  $P($there will be no people remaining when this $1$ person dies$)$ $=$ $P($no new person arrives during the lifetime of this $1$ person$)$ $=$ $P($$L$ $<$ $T$$)$ $=$ $\mu$ $/$ $(\mu + \lambda)$.  Is this approach reasonable?  Thank you for any help.

Comment: @MilesToGo Not quite - because another possibility is that someone (or more than one)  might arrive and then die before this person

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out!  Suppose at time $t$, we just have $1$ person. 
 $P($there will be no people remaining when this $1$ person dies$)$  $=$  $P($no new person arrives during the lifetime of this $1$ person$)$ $+$ $P($people arriving after time $t$ die before the lifetime of this $1$ person$)$  $=$  $P($$L$ $<$ $T$$)$ $+$ $P($lifetime of any new arrival $<$ lifetime of this $1$ person$)$  $=$  $[$$\mu$ $/$ $(\mu + \lambda)$$]$ $+$ $[1/2]$.  This is because the lifetime of any person is distributed as Exponential$(\mu)$.  Is this looking right?  Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: That is a different question and you could ask it separately, but $\frac{\mu}{\mu+\lambda} +\frac12$ is not correct - if $\mu > \lambda$ then you would get a probability over $1$

Comment: Thank you once again!  I'll work on it, and I have also asked this as a separate question.

Comment: Which you have at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4810768/how-to-calculate-probabilities-in-a-poisson-process-with-exponential-lifetime

Comment: Yes exactly! :)

Answer (score 1):

I will give a rough sketch. First, let $(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of independent exponentially distributed random variables with parameter $\mu$. Let $(Y_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be independent uniform random variables on $[0,s-t]$, and $N$ be Poisson distributed with parameter $\lambda (s-t)$. Everything shall be independent here. I can write $M(s-t) = \sum_{i=1}^N \mathbb{1}_{\{X_i > s-t-Y_i\}}$ in distribution. The argument is then that $M(s)$ given $M(t)=10$ is the sum of those 10 who have been alive at time $t$ and are still at time $s$ plus the sum of those who have been born after $t$ and are still alive at time $s$. Then we can use the independence and memorylessness of the exponential distribution and drop the condition in the variance. In particular,
$$
\mathsf{Var}[M(s)\mid M(t) = 10] = \mathsf{Var}\bigg[\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbb{1}_{\{X_i > s-t-Y_i\}}\bigg] + \mathsf{Var}\bigg[\sum_{i=1}^{10} \mathbb{1}_{\{X_i > s-t\}}\bigg] \\
= \sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^j \mathsf{Var}[\mathbb{1}_{\{N=j\}} \mathbb{1}_{\{X_i > s-t-Y_i\}}] + 10 \mathsf{Var}[ \mathbb{1}_{\{X_1 > s-t\}}] \\
=\sum_{j=0}^\infty j \big(\mathbb{P}(N=j)\mathbb{P}(X_1 > s-t-Y_1) - (\mathbb{P}(N=j)\mathbb{P}(X_1 > s-t-Y_1))^2\big) + 10(\mathbb{P}(X_1 > s-t) - \mathbb{P}(X_1 > s-t)^2).
$$
Can you take it from here?