# How to calculate probabilities in a Poisson process with exponential lifetime of arrivals?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, poisson-distribution

I have a Poisson process where people arrive at the rate of $λ$  --  so when an event occurs, a new person arrives.  This means that the times between successive arrivals are $T_i$ ~ Exponential $(\lambda)$.

And the lifetime of each person is independent Exponential $(μ)$.  That is, $L$ ~ Exponential $(\mu)$.

Further, let $M(t)$ be the number of people at time $t$.

Suppose at time $t$, we just have $1$ person.

I am trying to calculate the probability that there will be no people remaining when this $1$ person dies.

My attempt until now is as follows:

$P($there will be no people remaining when this $1$ person dies$)$

$=$ $P($no new person arrives during the lifetime of this $1$ person$)$ $+$ $P($someone or more than one person arrives after time $t$ and dies within the lifetime of this $1$ person$)$

$=$ $P(L < T)$ $+$ $P($one or more than one person arrives after time $t$ and dies before this $1$ person dies$)$

I calculated that $P($$L < T$$)$ $=$ $\frac{\mu}{\mu  +  \lambda}$,

because $L$ ~ Exponential $(\mu)$, and $T$ ~ Exponential $(\lambda)$.

Now, I am trying to calculate:

$P($one or more than one person arrives after time $t$ and dies before this $1$ person dies$)$

Could someone please point me to how I can find this probability?  Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you please show some working on how you got P(L < T)?

Comment: @insipidintegrator It is fairly standard that in a race between two independent Poisson processes with rates $\lambda$ and $\mu$, the probability the former happens first is $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}$.  You can find this with $\int \lambda e^{-\lambda t}\, e^{-\mu t} dt$

Comment: @Henry would you have some resources please? I'd be grateful. Thanks!

Comment: @insipidintegrator Just look at the first happening at time $t$ with density $\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$ and the second happening later than $t$ with probability $e^{-\mu t}$, and then integrate over $t$.

Comment: I just worked out the integral in Henry's comment step by step.  This gives $P(L < T)$ $=$ $\mu$ $/$ $(\mu + \lambda)$.

Comment: Ah thanks @Henry now I see it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is for the combined $P($there will be no people remaining when this $1$ person dies$)$:

Let's use $\ell$ for the lifetime of the $1$ person.

If there is another arrival at $t$ then the probability it survives to $\ell$ is $ e^{-\mu(\ell-t)}$.

Then, given $\ell$, the rate at which others arrive in $[0,\ell]$ and survive beyond $\ell$ is $\lambda e^{-\mu(\ell-t)}$

If you integrate this, you get $\int_{t=0}^\ell \lambda e^{-\mu(\ell-t)}\, dt =\frac{\lambda}{\mu}(1-e^{-\mu \ell})$

and this is the parameter of the Poisson distribution for the number of others alive at time $\ell$

so the probability there are no others alive at $\ell$ is $e^{-\frac{\lambda}{\mu}(1-e^{-\mu \ell})}$.

But $\ell$ is itself a random variable with an exponential distribution rate $\mu$

so we want $$\int_{\ell=0}^\infty e^{-\frac{\lambda}{\mu}(1-e^{-\mu \ell})} \, \mu e^{-\mu \ell} \, d\ell \\ = \frac{\mu}{\lambda}\left( 1- e^{-\lambda/\mu} \right). $$

- For $\lambda = \mu$ this gives $1-e^{-1} \approx 0.6321$, the answer to several other probability questions
- For $\lambda \gg \mu$ this gives almost $\frac{\mu}{\lambda}$ but still more than $\frac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu}$
- For $\lambda \ll \mu$ this gives a little more than $1-\frac{\lambda}{2\mu}$, also more than $\frac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu}$

Comment: Thank you!  I worked through all the steps and have now understood how to think about this.  One clarification please:  To find the rate that changes with time here, we calculate the probability that any other arrival in $[0, l]$ survives beyond time $l$.  Given that there's $1$ particle that's alive at time $t$, is it correct that any other arrival can occur at *any* point in time $t$ that's between $0$ and $l$?  And this is why we integrate from $0$ to $l$.  So, the rate changes with time as it depends on the time when any other arrival occurs, which is between $[0, l]$.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @MilesToGo Yes - the rate at which arrivals occur between $0$ and $\ell$ is a constant $\lambda$.  But we are only interested in the rate of arrivals who are going to survive beyond $\ell$, and this is going to vary, and be higher the closer time $t$ gets to $\ell$: the variable rate $\lambda e^{-\mu(\ell-t)}$ does this, increasing from $\lambda e^{-\mu\ell}$ when $t=0$ to $\lambda$ when $t=\ell$.  You then integrate to find the expected number of surviving arrivals between $t=0$ and $t=\ell$.

Comment: This explanation makes it even more clear!  Thank you so much for your time!!